# linq group by where count

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

| name | work date |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2022-3-5 |
| a | 2022-3-6 |
| a | 2022-3-7 |
| b | 2022-3-6 |
| b | 2022-3-7 |
| c | 2022-3-7 |

the result i want,I want to count how many days each person has worked, and summarize two report.

| people | work days |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 1 |

| >=3day | >=2day | >=1day | total people | total workdays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

I want to get the number of >=3 days count1 = 1 >=2 days of number count2 = 2 >1 day of number count3 = 3 and assign them to three different variables，I try to do this

```cs
int count1 = items.GroupBy(g => g.date).Where(w => w.Count() >= 3).Count();
int count2 = items.GroupBy(g => g.date).Where(w => w.Count() >= 2).Count();
int count3 = items.GroupBy(g => g.date).Where(w => w.Count() >= 1).Count();
```

I hope
`count1=1`group name(a) people count = 1
`count2=2`group name(a,b) people count = 2
`count3=3`group name(a,b,c) people count = 3
how can i modify my linq statement。

Comment: Can you describe the desired result and the result you got with the code you have tested.

Comment: @Magnus I want to get the number of >3 days equal to 1 >2 days of number equal to 2 >1 day of number equal to 3 and assign them to three different variables

Comment: The same date does not occur more than 3 times in the table. `2022-3-7` occur exactly 3 times.

Comment: in my honest opinion, this question is very confusing at best. you can group the `name` and still get `a` occurs more than equal to 3 times.. :(

Comment: I've updated my question again with an example of the result

Comment: This is probably a language problem, but your description of the problem is a bit confusing.  So, let me try to work out what you are saying.  Group 3 (>=1day) is three, because all three dates in items  have at least one record.  While count1 (>=3 day) is 1, because only one date has at least three records.  Correct?

Comment: yes,I want to count how many days each person worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm correct in my comment above, this should give you something close to what you want.

```
void Main()
{
    var counts = (from i in Items()
        group i by i.date into r    // group by dates
        group r by r.Count() into s // group by count per date
        select new {PerDay=s.Key, Cnt= s.Count()}   
    ).ToList();

}

record Item(string name, DateTime date);

IEnumerable<Item> Items()
{
    return new List<Item> {
        new Item("a", new DateTime(2022, 3, 5)),
        new Item("a", new DateTime(2022, 3, 6)),
        new Item("a", new DateTime(2022, 3, 7)),
        new Item("b", new DateTime(2022, 3, 6)),
        new Item("b", new DateTime(2022, 3, 7)),
        new Item("c", new DateTime(2022, 3, 7)),
        new Item("d", new DateTime(2022, 3, 8)),
        new Item("d", new DateTime(2022, 3, 9)),
        new Item("f", new DateTime(2022, 3, 10)),
        new Item("f", new DateTime(2022, 3, 10)),
        new Item("f", new DateTime(2022, 3, 10)),
        new Item("f", new DateTime(2022, 3, 10)),
        new Item("e", new DateTime(2022, 3, 9))
};

// 5-Mar = 1
// 6-Mar = 2
// 7-Mar = 3
// 8-Mar = 1
// 9-Mar = 2
// 10-Mar = 4

}
```

This will give you a list of objects which look like this.

```
PerDay  Cnt
 1       2
 2       2
 3       1
 4       1
```

To compress that down to just the three values you want, to this:

```
var counts2 = counts.ToLookup(c=> (c.PerDay > 2 ? 3 : c.PerDay),  c=>c.Cnt)  // group all > 2 into 3
                    .ToDictionary(c =>c.Key, c=>c.Sum() ); // merge individual counts
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I want too. How many days do I need each person to work a=3 b=2 c=1.....

Comment: I need to count >=3day people count=1  >=2day people count=3

Comment: `counts2[1]` is count of days with 1 record.  `counts2[2]` is count of days with 2 records.  `counts2[3]` is count of days with 3 or more records.

Comment: I need to count the number of people who work for three days，I updated my question。